# Set creation and update time with Hibernate in Xml mappings

Tags: hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping, hbm

I'm using Hibernate with **Xml** mappings. I have an entity that has two fields *creationDate* and *updateDate* of type `timestamp`, that have to be filled with the current UTC time when the entity is persisted and updated.
I know about the existence of the `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` annotations, but i don't know how to use their equivalent in my Xml mappings.

Again, i was wondering if Hibernate somehow supports natively the update and creation time set.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I know about the existence of the `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` annotations, but i don't know how to use their equivalent in my Xml mappings.

The Hibernate3 [event architecture](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html#objectstate-events) provides something equivalent and you could register listeners for `PreInsertEvent`, `PreUpdateEvent` or `SaveOrUpdateEvent` (see the `org.hibernate.event` package for a full list) to set and update the create/update dates.

Another approach would be to use an [interceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html#objectstate-interceptors), either `Session`-scoped or `SessionFactory`-scoped and to set both `createDate` and `updateDate` in `onSave(...)`, update the `updateDate` in `onFlushDirty(...)`.

---

**Update:** I'm leaving my original suggestions below but I think that the right approach (should have been my initial answer) is to use an interceptor or the event architecture.

<strike>You could use the **`generated`** attribute of the **[`timestamp`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-timestamp)** to get **`creationDate`** and **`updateDate`** generated by the database on insert and on insert and update respectively:</strike>

```
<class name="MyEntity" table="MY_ENTITY">
  <id .../>
  <timestamp name="createDate" generated="insert" ... />
  <timestamp name="updateDate" generated="always" ... />
  ...
</class>
```

Refer to the section on [generated properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-generated) for full details.

#### Option 1

It appears that **`timestamp`** doesn't support [**`generatead`**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-generated) so my suggestion won't work. Nevertheless, having read the documentation more carefully, my understanding is that **`timestamp`** is an alternative to versioning and I don't think that it's an appropriate choice for fields like **`createDate`** and **`updateDate`** (it may work for the later but that's not what `timestamp` is for).

So I would actually still use [generated properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-generated) **but** with [simple properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-property) instead of **`timestamp`**:

```
<class name="MyEntity" table="MY_ENTITY">
  <id .../>
  <property name="createDate" update="false" insert="false" generated="insert" ... />
  <property name="updateDate" update="false" insert="false" generated="always" ... />
  ...
</class>
```

At the database level, this would require using a trigger for `updateDate` column. For the `createDate` column, using something like `current_timestamp` as default value would work nicely. But triggers are maybe not wanted...

#### Option 2

To avoid the trigger of the **Option 1**, a variation would be to use `updateDate` for versioning (and thus map it as `timestamp`):

```
<class name="MyEntity" table="MY_ENTITY">
  <id .../>
  <timestamp name="updateDate" ... />
  <property name="createDate" update="false" insert="false" generated="insert" ... />
  ...
</class>
```

Same approach as Option 1 for `createDate`, use a default value at the database level.

#### Option 3

See the top of this answer...

Comment: That's nice. But which type should i set for the createDate and updateDate properties...you code snippet ends before the type attribute :)

Comment: @Marco The `type` attribute is optional. If you use a `java.util.Date` at the Java level, there is no need to specify it.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway this solution involves the creation of specific database triggers right?

Comment: @Marco For the updateDate, indeed (the createDate could just use a "default" value). I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Timestamps in Hibernate are apparently always updated automatically when the entity changes, so you can't use a `<timestamp>` mapping for the creation date. However, you can store it as a simple `java.util.Date` property, initialized it with `new Date()`.

For the update timestamp, try this:

```
public class MyEntity {
  ...
  private Date updateDate;
  ...
}

<class name="MyEntity" table="MY_ENTITY">
  <id .../>
  <timestamp name="updateDate" access="field" column="UPDATE_DATE"/>
  ...
</class>
```

Note that `timestamp` must come right after `id` in the mapping.

FYI here is a [reference of the `timestamp` attributes](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-timestamp).

Comment: You can control this behavior with the `generated` attribute.

Comment: @Pascal The reference linked above states: "`insert`: the given property value is generated on insert, but is not regenerated on subsequent updates. [...] Even though `version` and `timestamp` properties can be marked as `generated`, this option is not available."

Comment: Indeed, you're right. I went too fast. And now that I've re-read the doc carefully, I even wonder if one should use `timestamp` for "regular" fields like `createDate` or `updateDate` (my understanding is that you should use `timestamp` for `versioning` and this explains why `generated` doesn't make sense for `timestamp`), this seems to be an abuse of `timestamp`.

Comment: @Pascal True, albeit a pretty common one (judging from the number of examples I found on the web). Which is sort of understandable as the other options listed in your answer all are more complicated, requiring triggers/interceptors/event listeners...

Comment: To be honest, I find that the documentation on `generated` sucks, it's unclear and misleading. (BTW, I didn't mean to harass you with my comment, I made a big typo that I wanted to fix, hence the delete/repost).

Comment: @Pascal That's what I thought, I didn't perceive anything offending in what you did :-)